# Display forecast in ggplot based table (R)

Tags: r, forecasting, vector-autoregression, ggplot2

Is there any way to display the output of `forecast` to a `ggplot` based table? The table should contain the input values as well as the forecasted values

```
library(vars)
library(fpp)
VARselect(usconsumption, lag.max = 3, type="const")$selection
var <- VAR(usconsumption, p=1,type = "both",lag.max = 3)
serial.test(var, lags.pt = 3,type = "PT.asymptotic")

fcst <- forecast(var)
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you mean by a "ggplot based table". Perhaps you mean something like the following.

```
library(ggplot2)
autoplot(fcst)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Rob, Thanks for the response. Is there any way I could export the data from the graphs to an excel or another table(requires the predicted value too). Is there any way to convert the data from type mforcast to dataframe?

Comment: If you are using the current github version of the forecast package, you can use `as.data.frame(fcst$forecast[[1]])` and `as.data.frame(fcst$forecast[[2]])`. I will update as.data.frame to enable this to happen in one call.

Comment: `as.data.frame.mforecast` now works in github version. Should be on CRAN in next week or two.